# My Jura coffee machine doesn't pour espresso

Tags: espresso, coffee-machines

The machine operates okay with milk, but when espresso program is activated, machine acts like it is making it (grinds coffee, than heats water) but nothing comes out of the tube. The milk steaming part operates as usual.

Have anybody had experience with Jura maintenance? What are the steps to point a problem?

Comment: Will it make longer black coffees? Will it pour coffee into milky drinks?

Comment: @fredley no, it does not make americano nor cappucino, if I get you correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the grinder or the brew group are clogged. You might want to open up the machine and clean the burrs and the brew group. Afterwards, grind coarser and make sure not to use oily beans.

Answer (score 0):

Very belated comment: somebody has been selling cheap Jura-compatible ("Claris") filters filled with vermiculite (rather than activated carbon) and with an inadequate egress filter.

I've bought myself a Jura Impressa XS90 with the eventual intention of adding voice control and a carousel for the beans, based on its diagnostic protocol being fairly well-understood. Needless to say it wasn't new and needed a fair amount of fettling, and removing accumulated flaky bits from the non-return valve immediately after the pump fixed a lot of issues... to the extent that I find myself wondering whether that is the root cause of the many problems reported in the flowmeter/regulator area.